# GitLab CI&CD test coverage with jacoco

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-ci, jacoco

In GitLab 15.0 test coverage feature in settings project will be removed.

GitLab offers to parse test coverage with `coverage` keyword in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

All requirements are met:

1. Defined as single-quoted string.
2. A regular expression starts and ends with the / character.

Why test-coverage badge is still showing `unknown`?

```
test:
  stage: test
  script: gradle check
  coverage: '/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%./'
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      junit: build/test-results/test/**/TEST-*.xml
```

Comment: What does the console output look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get `./gradlew test` to output a summary of test coverage, I needed to add [`gradle-jacoco-log`](https://gitlab.com/barfuin/gradle-jacoco-log/-/blob/master/README.md) to my project.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.barfuin.gradle.jacocolog' version '2.0.0'
}

test {
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
  dependsOn test
}
```

Which gives me the following console output:

```bash
> Task :jacocoLogTestCoverage
Test Coverage:
    - Class Coverage: 100%
    - Method Coverage: 83.6%
    - Branch Coverage: 75%
    - Line Coverage: 85.5%
    - Instruction Coverage: 83.1%
    - Complexity Coverage: 82.5%
```

I can then choose to report `Instruction Coverage` to GitLab by adding the following to `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
test:
  stage: test
  script: gradle check
  coverage: '/    - Instruction Coverage: ([0-9.]+)%/'
```

Comment: Thank you! By adding the `coverage: ` line to the Ci/CD YAML script now the coverage percentage is back in the GitLab dashboard